# Save and Publish button not working after installing SSL

Tags: publish, ssl

I'm having a trouble editing my wp page.
I installed an SSL certificate and everything on the page works fine. However, when I try to edit the page through Wordpress Customizer it doesn't let me save the changes. When I click the "Save and Publish" button it doesn't work. I'm thinking it could be because of the SSL but i don't know what to edit to make it work. Please help!

Thanks

Comment: 1) Flush the cache; 2) Login into WordPress Admin Dashboard, and go to WordPress Settings and change the WordPress Address (URL) and the Site Address (URL) from HTTP to HTTPS; 3) check your access.log for the clue.